# How to update data in table if data is match other then insert in mysql

Tags: mysql

Insert a row in sql if any match then update it.

I tried it

```
INSERT INTO test (name, email)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere@s.com') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM test WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM `test`;

+----+--------+-----------------+
| id | name   | email           |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | Rupert | Somewhere@s.com | 
+----+--------+-----------------+
```

This is only work for checking duplicate entry. but i want if no enrty found then insert it or other than update it.

```
INSERT INTO test (name, email)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere@somewhere.com') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM test WHERE name = 'Rupert'
) LIMIT 1;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM `test`;

+----+--------+-----------------+
| id | name   | email           |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | Rupert | Somewhere@s.com | 
+----+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want update row in mysql if match with where condition. if not match so insert a row in mysql.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I tried this

INSERT INTO test(name,email) VALUES ('abhi','abhi@a.com')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='abhi';
UPDATE test set name='abhishek' email='abhishek@a.com'
WHERE name = 'abhi';

this is showing me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to RUN this query

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT email UNIQUE (email);
```

*After Then use this it will update your record if exist*

```
INSERT INTO test (name,email) VALUES ('Gorilla','Somewhere@s.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = "Somewhere@somewhere.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`

first, you have to create unique index:
`ALTER TABLE`  test`ADD UNIQUE email(`email`);

thus, if you insert a record with the same email value, it will update the record.

```
INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES("Rupert", "Somewhere@s.com") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name="Rupert", email="Somewhere@s.com"
```

if it's a new email, it will create a new record